# get consensus of multiple partitioning methods in R

Tags: r, algorithm, classification, cluster-analysis, partitioning

My data:

```
data=cbind(c(1,1,2,1,1,3),c(1,1,2,1,1,1),c(2,2,1,2,1,2))
colnames(data)=paste("item",1:3)
rownames(data)=paste("method",1:6)
```

I want as an output that according to majority vote, there are two communities (with their elements). Something like: `group1={item1, item2}`, `group2={item3}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is passed a matrix where each column is an item and each row is a membership vector corresponding to a partition of the items according to a clustering method. The elements (numbers) composing each row have no meaning other than indicating membership and are recycled from row to row. The function returns the majority vote partition. When no consensus exists for an item, the partition given by the first row wins. This allows ordering of the partitions by decreasing values of modularity, for instance.

```
    consensus.final <-
  function(data){
    output=list()
    for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
      row=as.numeric(data[i,])
      output.inner=list()
      for (j in 1:length(row)){
        group=character()
        group=c(group,colnames(data)[which(row==row[j])])
        output.inner[[j]]=group
      }
      output.inner=unique(output.inner)
      output[[i]]=output.inner
    }

    # gives the mode of the vector representing the number of groups found by each method
    consensus.n.comm=as.numeric(names(sort(table(unlist(lapply(output,length))),decreasing=TRUE))[1])

    # removes the elements of the list that do not correspond to this consensus solution
    output=output[lapply(output,length)==consensus.n.comm]

    # 1) find intersection 
    # 2) use majority vote for elements of each vector that are not part of the intersection

    group=list()

    for (i in 1:consensus.n.comm){ 
      list.intersection=list()
      for (p in 1:length(output)){
        list.intersection[[p]]=unlist(output[[p]][i])
      }

      # candidate group i
      intersection=Reduce(intersect,list.intersection)
      group[[i]]=intersection

      # we need to reinforce that group
      for (p in 1:length(list.intersection)){
        vector=setdiff(list.intersection[[p]],intersection)
        if (length(vector)>0){
          for (j in 1:length(vector)){
            counter=vector(length=length(list.intersection))
            for (k in 1:length(list.intersection)){
              counter[k]=vector[j]%in%list.intersection[[k]]
            }
            if(length(which(counter==TRUE))>=ceiling((length(counter)/2)+0.001)){
              group[[i]]=c(group[[i]],vector[j])
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    group=lapply(group,unique)

    # variables for which consensus has not been reached
    unclassified=setdiff(colnames(data),unlist(group))

    if (length(unclassified)>0){
      for (pp  in 1:length(unclassified)){
        temp=matrix(nrow=length(output),ncol=consensus.n.comm)
        for (i in 1:nrow(temp)){
          for (j in 1:ncol(temp)){
            temp[i,j]=unclassified[pp]%in%unlist(output[[i]][j])
          }
        }
        # use the partition of the first method when no majority exists (this allows ordering of partitions by decreasing modularity values for instance)
        index.best=which(temp[1,]==TRUE)
        group[[index.best]]=c(group[[index.best]],unclassified[pp])
      }
    }
    output=list(group=group,unclassified=unclassified)
  }
```

Some examples:

```
data=cbind(c(1,1,2,1,1,3),c(1,1,2,1,1,1),c(2,2,1,2,1,2))
colnames(data)=paste("item",1:3)
rownames(data)=paste("method",1:6)
data
consensus.final(data)$group

[[1]]
[1] "item 1" "item 2"

[[2]]
[1] "item 3"

data=cbind(c(1,1,1,1,1,3),c(1,1,1,1,1,1),c(1,1,1,2,1,2)) 
colnames(data)=paste("item",1:3) 
rownames(data)=paste("method",1:6)
data
consensus.final(data)$group

[[1]]
[1] "item 1" "item 2" "item 3"

data=cbind(c(1,3,2,1),c(2,2,3,3),c(3,1,1,2))
colnames(data)=paste("item",1:3)
rownames(data)=paste("method",1:4)
data
consensus.final(data)$group

[[1]]
[1] "item 1"

[[2]]
[1] "item 2"

[[3]]
[1] "item 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, base `R`:

```
res=apply(data,2,function(u) as.numeric(names(sort(table(u), decreasing=T))[1]))

setNames(lapply(unique(res), function(u) names(res)[res==u]), unique(res))
#$`1`
#[1] "item 1" "item 2"

#$`2`
#[1] "item 3"
```

Comment: sorry, that does not work. For instance:
data=cbind(c(1,1,1,1,1,3),c(1,1,1,1,1,1),c(1,1,1,2,1,2))
colnames(data)=paste("item",1:3)
rownames(data)=paste("method",1:6)
Your method returns 3 groups while there is clearly only one cluster based on majority vote, as highlighted by: consensus.n.comm=trunc(mean(n.comm))
consensus.n.comm

Comment: Edited. A typo on names and order. Your second example is fully reflected through the code.

Comment: I found a new problem: take for instance: data=cbind(c(1,3,2,1),c(2,2,3,3),c(3,1,1,2)); colnames(data)=paste("item",1:3); rownames(data)=paste("method",1:4)
Your commands return {item1,item3} and {item 2} when the consensus is clearly a 3 clusters solution. 
Remember that the numbers are not fixed group labels, they only indicate membership and are recycled from row to row

Comment: In case of equality (column 2), do you mean you want two groups?

Comment: for each row (each method), the three items are classified in different groups. I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "in the case of equality (column 2)".

Comment: what I mean is that method 1 found 3 clusters, as well as methods 2, 3 and 4. Each method outputs a membership vector using labels (from 1 to 3), but these labels only have meaning within their own row. they only show that item 1 is in a different group than item 2 and that item 2 is in a different group than item 3 and so forth, according to the clustering method corresponding to that particular row

Comment: i am not so sure I understood correctly the wanted output so .... could you clarify in that case what is the wanted result?

Comment: Well, in that case, the output should be that a majority (actually in this example, all) of the methods partitioned the items into 3 clusters, and that these three clusters are {item 1}, {item 2}, and {item 3}

Comment: in other words, the output gives the partitioning solution that was found by the majority of the clustering methods, plus the composition of the clusters, again, based on consensus