# R: potential issue with igraph 1.0.0 layout algorithms

Tags: r, version, igraph

Please load the following function:

```
weight.community <- function(row,membership,weigth.within,weight.between) {
        if(as.numeric(membership[which(names(membership)==row[1])])==as.numeric(membership[which(names(membership)==row[2])])){
        weight=weigth.within
        }else{
        weight=weight.between
        }
        return(weight)
        }
dump(weight.community,"weight.community.R")
source("weight.community.R")
```

Now, here is my issue: with `igraph<1.0.0`, the following commands:

```
g=erdos.renyi.game(10,0.5)
V(g)$names=as.character(1:10)
membership=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5))
names(membership)=V(g)$names
E(g)$weight=apply(get.edgelist(g),1,weight.community,membership,50,1)
g$layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold(g,weights=E(g)$weight)
plot(g)
```

used to give me a graph where vertices were grouped based on community membership (like shown in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390221/how-to-make-grouped-layout-in-igraph/29098951#29098951)). But in the new version of igraph, it seems that `layout.fruchterman.reingold` is not responsive to edge weights anymore. I tried the new function name `layout_with_fr`, with the same outcome. And the same thing happens with `layout.kamada.kawai`.

I know from these [release notes](http://igraph.org/2015/06/24/igraph-1.0.0-r.html) that

> Fruchterman-Reingold and Kamada-Kawai layout algorithms rewritten from
>   scratch

So, that might explain me running into trouble. I would appreciate any guidance on how to approach this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a bug in the C core of igraph that was introduced in 1.0.0. If you look at the source code of `layout_fr.c`, you can see that the `weights` argument is not used anywhere in the layout functions.

Please file an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues) if you would like to get this fixed.

Comment: thank for this explanation, will do. Until the issue is fixed, going back to an earlier version of igraph would work, right? The problem is that I tried to install igraph `0.7.0` or `0.7.1` from http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/igraph but it does not seem to be compatible with R `3.2.1`

Comment: I am sure that 0.7.1 is compatible, you just need to build it from source.

Comment: I will (re-)add support for the weights in a sec: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/839

Comment: thanks a lot. When it is done, where can I download the version of igraph with the fix?

Comment: @GaborCsardi when I download igraph 0.7.0 from the archive on CRAN and do `install.packages("C:\Users\User1\Desktop\igraph_0.7.0.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="‌​source")` to install from source, I get: `* installing *source* package 'igraph' ... ** package 'igraph' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127 ERROR: configuration failed for package 'igraph'`

Comment: and right before the error I also get the warning: `Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127`

Comment: It was 0.7.1, and it has to work in general, because that was the version on CRAN, until about three week ago. You can probably even build it on win-builder.r-project.org.

Comment: Btw. this was also fixed in the development version of igraph.