# layout.fruchterman.reingold vs. layout_with_fr

Tags: r, layout, igraph

I upgraded from R 3.0 to R 3.2.1. In the new version of igraph, the Fruchterman-Reingold layout changed from layout.fruchterman.reingold to layout_with_fr. However, the two functions produce completely different networks (using Twitter data). It would seem that layout.fruchterman.reingold differs significantly from layout_with_fr. Using the layout_with_fr all my networks collapse to a single point in the lower left corner of the graph. Has anyone encounter similar problems?

Comment: Go read [the update news](https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/blob/dev/inst/NEWS.md) - they rewrote these functions from scratch in version 1.0 - It depends on what versions you have switched between for exact changes

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy. I think the problem is this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432176/r-potential-issue-with-igraph-1-0-0-layout-algorithms

Comment: This is the same code in R 3.0 and in R 3.2. The new code is not producing proper layouts: https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/110

Comment: you should add the version of igraph you were using in both examples to help trouble shooting (get it from `sessionInfo()`)

Comment: Will do in the future. gaborcsardi was kind enough to take a look at the code. There was a bug in the FR algorithm that is now being reviewed. You can see the exchange here: https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/110#issuecomment-133625104