# igraph: Specify weights in a layout algorithm

Tags: r, igraph

I found multiple postings (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390221/how-to-make-grouped-layout-in-igraph) and [here](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2007-06/msg00023.html)) that illustrate how to modify a layout by adding an edge weight.

Still when I do

```
require(igraph)

g <- graph.ring(10)

plot(g)

set.seed(28100)
E(g)$weight <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)
E(g)$weight 
# [1] 4 3 4 6 2 9 5 2 9 7
l <- layout_with_fr(g, weights=E(g)$weight)

plot(g, layout=l)
```

with `R version 3.2.2` and `igraph version 1.0.1` I got the exact same layout. What instead I would expect to obtain is a layout where edges with a higher (lower) weight are shorter (longer). In other words, nodes connected by an edge with a higher weight are relative closer to each other than nodes connected by a low-weight edge.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The layout changes slightly when I run the code. What behaviour/layout are you looking for? Please elaborate. `R version 3.2.0, graph version 1.0.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is/was a bug in the new Fruchterman-Reingold layout implementation (starting from igraph 1.0.0) which made it ignore the weights. This has [already been fixed](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/839) in the development version, but it seems like this version was not released yet. You can install the development version from Github with the `devtools` package:

```
devtools::install_github("gaborcsardi/pkgconfig")
devtools::install_github("igraph/rigraph")
```

Comment: Indeed, it was a bug.