# (igraph) Grouped layout based on attribute

Tags: r, igraph

I'm using the iGraph package in R to layout a network graph, and I would like to group the vertex coordinates based on attribute values.

Similar to the answered question [How to make grouped layout in igraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390221/how-to-make-grouped-layout-in-igraph), my question differs in that the nodes needn't be grouped by a community membership that was derived from a community detection algorithm.

Rather, I want to layout with groups based on attribute values that are known in advance for each vertex.

For example, if each vertex has an attribute "Master.Org", and there are ~10 to ~20 distinct values for Master.Org, then how can I layout the graph such that all vertices within the same Master.Org are grouped ?

Thanks!

**Additional Detail**

In fact, two separate attributes provide nested levels of grouping.

My goal is to layout a graph object such that the "Master.Org" and "Org.Of" values are grouped together in their XY coordinates on the graph.

For example, each node will belong to an "Org.Of".  And there can be multiple "Org.Of" values within the "Master.Org".

Thoughts ?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm still working on this, and still challenged.  Basically, because the data is an org chart, I already know the community breaks and where they lie.  And each node has an attribute to indicate which "community" they are in.  My challenge, then, is to layout the graph appropriately, by using these attributes as input to a weighting mechanism like the one described above.  Thoughts ?  Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

While this question is rather old, it is a reasonable question and deserves an answer.

No data was provided so I will generate an arbitrary example.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1234)
G = erdos.renyi.game(20, 0.25)
V(G)$Group1 = sample(3,20, replace=TRUE)
plot(G, vertex.color=rainbow(3, alpha=0.4)[V(G)$Group1])
```

[image: Original Graph]

Without doing anything,  the Group is ignored.

Now,  we need to create a layout that will plot nodes 
in the same group close together.  We can do this by creating
a graph with the same nodes, but with additional links between 
nodes in the same group. The within-group links will be given 
a high weight and the original links will be given a small weight. 
This will cluster nodes in the same group. We then apply the
layout to plotting the *original* graph, without the extra links. 
They were just to get a good layout.

```
G_Grouped = G
E(G_Grouped)$weight = 1

## Add edges with high weight between all nodes in the same group
for(i in unique(V(G)$Group1)) {
    GroupV = which(V(G)$Group1 == i)
    G_Grouped = add_edges(G_Grouped, combn(GroupV, 2), attr=list(weight=5))
} 

## Now create a layout based on G_Grouped
set.seed(567)
LO = layout_with_fr(G_Grouped)

## Use the layout to plot the original graph
plot(G, vertex.color=rainbow(3, alpha=0.4)[V(G)$Group1], layout=LO)
```

[image: Graph with nodes clustered by group]

If you want to go beyond this to have multiple levels of grouping, just add additional links with appropriate weights to connect the subgroups too.

Comment: is it possible to convert 'V(G)$Group1' to the 'communities object' in your example?

Comment: @Nick,  yes! Suppose that you have run `CLG = cluster_louvain(G)` in the example above. You can do exactly what I did above but every time that I wrote `V(G)$Group1` replace it with `CLG$membership`.  It should work fine.