# Visualize a Large Graph Network in R

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization, igraph, graph-visualization

I have around 100,000 rows in a dataframe and I need to visualize it using a network graph in R. However, since there is too much data, it is very difficult to analyze visually and I am not sure how to do this since I am new in R.

This is what I am aiming for:

[image]

And this is what my df looks like:

| Location | Manager |
| --- | --- |
| L1 | M1 |
| L2 | M3 |
| L76 | M1 |
| L34 | M1 |
| L45 | M1 |
| L18 | M4 |
| L98 | M7 |
| L145 | M4 |
| L134 | M1 |
| L22 | M5 |
| L5 | M7 |
| L56 | M7 |
| L11 | M8 |
| L76 | M5 |

For example, location L22 should be connected to location L76 since they have M5 in common, and so on. I also want the weight of the line connecting these locations to be based on the number of managers they have in common.

Thanks!

Comment: But surely a graph of the size you describe would be uninterpretable visually? What is the message that you want to convey with your visualisation?

Comment: A place to start could br creating a weighted adjaceny matrix with `adj = tcrossprod(table(d))` . Then just use standard graph tools e.g. `igraph`

Comment: ... and *lots* of examples for changing node size and edge weight : you'll find a bunch of examples at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+igraph+edge+thickness and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+igraph+node+size

Comment: Since your example desired graph came from [Previous Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64729226/4752675),  did you try the code there?  What did not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use the `igraph` package like below

```
library(igraph)
g <- simplify(
  graph_from_data_frame(
    do. Call(
      rbind,
      lapply(
        split(df, ~Manager),
        function(v) {
          with(
            v,
            if (length(Location) > 1) {
              make_full_graph(length(Location)) %>%
                set_vertex_attr(name = "name", value = Location) %>%
                set_edge_attr(name = "width", value = length(Manager)) %>%
                get.data.frame()
            } else {
              data. Frame(from = Location, to = Location, width = 1)
            }
          )
        }
      )
    ),
    directed = FALSE
  ),
  edge.attr.comb = "sum"
)
```

and you will obtain

```
> g
IGRAPH d49cf33 UN-- 13 15 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), width (e/n)
+ edges from d49cf33 (vertex names):
 [1] L1 --L76  L1 --L34  L1 --L45  L1 --L134 L76--L34  L76--L45  L76--L22
 [8] L76--L134 L34--L45  L34--L134 L45--L134 L18--L145 L98--L5   L98--L56
[15] L5 --L56
```

and the network plot (run `plot(g)`)

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work for me, the connections between the locations do not show up at all

Comment: @melisa you'd better show how your desired output looks like. I have no clue what you are after.