# How to create a network representing different clusters with other information?

Tags: python, r, data-visualization, networkx, igraph

I have a dataframe `nodes` with information that looks like below:

```
dput(nodes)

structure(list(Names = c("A4GALT", "AASS", "ABCA10", "ABCA7", 
"ABCD4", "ABHD4", "ABTB1", "AC006978.2", "AC009119.2"), type = c("typeA", 
"typeA", "typeC", "typeA", "typeC", "typeC", "typeB", "typeB", 
"typeB"), type_num = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Clusters = c("Cluster1", 
"Cluster1", "Cluster2", "Cluster3", "Cluster3", "Cluster1", "Cluster2", 
"Cluster3", "Cluster2")), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

So, in the `nodes` dataframe, there are 4 columns. `Names` is the gene name, `type` is different types, `type_num` is the number given to each genetype and column `Clusters` show 3 clusters in which each gene belong to.

Similarly, I have other dataframe `edges` with with information like below:

dput(edges)

```
structure(list(fromNode = c("A4GALT", "A4GALT", "A4GALT", "A4GALT", 
"A4GALT", "A4GALT", "A4GALT", "A4GALT", "AASS", "AASS", "AASS", 
"AASS", "AASS", "AASS", "AASS", "ABCA10", "ABCA10", "ABCA10", 
"ABCA10", "ABCA10", "ABCA10", "ABCA7", "ABCA7", "ABCA7", "ABCA7", 
"ABCA7", "ABCD4", "ABCD4", "ABCD4", "ABCD4", "ABHD4", "ABHD4", 
"ABHD4", "ABTB1", "ABTB1", "AC006978.2"), toNode = c("AASS", 
"ABCA10", "ABCA7", "ABCD4", "ABHD4", "ABTB1", "AC006978.2", "AC009119.2", 
"ABCA10", "ABCA7", "ABCD4", "ABHD4", "ABTB1", "AC006978.2", "AC009119.2", 
"ABCA7", "ABCD4", "ABHD4", "ABTB1", "AC006978.2", "AC009119.2", 
"ABCD4", "ABHD4", "ABTB1", "AC006978.2", "AC009119.2", "ABHD4", 
"ABTB1", "AC006978.2", "AC009119.2", "ABTB1", "AC006978.2", "AC009119.2", 
"AC006978.2", "AC009119.2", "AC009119.2"), weight = c(0.005842835, 
0.002253695, 0.014513253, 0.004851739, 0.066702792, 0.009418991, 
0.001136938, 0.000474221, 0.004405601, 0.000666001, 0.005625977, 
0.0333554, 0.004666223, 0.000103131, 0.00026302, 0.004514819, 
0.029632695, 0.001825839, 0.028379806, 0.001403298, 0.008339397, 
0.02393394, 0.004782329, 0.024767355, 0.002986813, 0.00559471, 
0.005961539, 0.064831874, 0.013023138, 0.027935729, 0.006618816, 
0.001134219, 0.012798368, 0.007961242, 0.01640476, 0.007997743
), direction = c("undirected", "undirected", "undirected", "undirected", 
"undirected", "undirected", "undirected", "undirected", "undirected", 
"undirected", "undirected", "undirected", "undirected", "undirected", 
"undirected", "undirected", "undirected", "undirected", "undirected", 
"undirected", "undirected", "undirected", "undirected", "undirected", 
"undirected", "undirected", "undirected", "undirected", "undirected", 
"undirected", "undirected", "undirected", "undirected", "undirected", 
"undirected", "undirected")), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Tried with `igraph` but didn't look the way I want.

```
library(igraph)
net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=edges, vertices=nodes, directed=F)

as_edgelist(net, names=T)
as_adjacency_matrix(net, attr="weight")

# Removing loops from the graph:
net <- simplify(net, remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T) 

# Let's and reduce the arrow size and remove the labels:
plot(net, edge.arrow.size=.4,vertex.label=NA)
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone please help me how to create a network like above with the data given above. Any help is appreciated. thank you in advance.

Comment: Your example data is not useable The Nodes data frame and the Edges data frame contain different nodes.   However, the answer to [Grouped layout based on attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37378744/4752675) shows how to make a plot  that groups nodes by cluster

Comment: @G5W thanks a lot for reply. I changed the data in the above post now. Please check now they have same nodes. Could you please help me how to plot that with the above data? thanq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a repetition of the answer to [Grouped layout based on attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37378744/4752675).

I *think* that you want to group the vertices by the `Clusters` attribute and color them using the `type` attribute. I will do that in this answer.
Your code creating the network is fine, but a simple plot does not group the vertices by the clusters (I have added coloring the vertices by type).

```
plot(net, edge.arrow.size=.4,vertex.label=NA, 
    vertex.color=as.numeric(factor(nodes$type)))
```

[image: Ungrouped network plot]

What you need is a layout that will emphasize the clusters. The previous answer cited above shows how to do that by generating a different graph with the same vertices but with heavy edge weights between vertices in the same cluster. In your case, it would be

```
Grouped.net = net
E(Grouped.net)$weight = 1

## Add edges with high weight between all nodes in the same group
for(Clus in unique(nodes$Clusters)) {
    GroupV = which(nodes$Clusters == Clus)
    Grouped.net = add_edges(Grouped.net, combn(GroupV, 2), attr=list(weight=80))
} 

## Now create a layout based on G_Grouped
set.seed(567)
LO = layout_with_fr(Grouped.net)

## Use the layout to plot the original graph
plot(net, layout=LO, edge.arrow.size=.4,vertex.label=NA, 
    vertex.color=as.numeric(factor(nodes$type)))
```

[image: network grouped by cluster]

If you have a large number of vertices,  you may also wish to reduce their size with vertex.size=4

Comment: thank you very much. Very useful. But I need small help. I'm applying this code for a huge data and it looks like this [https://i.imgur.com/MsPhXOL.png] 1) Here I want to name the clusters in the image. 2) I'm not able to see `typeC` Is there a way to bring those `typeC` on the top. 3) How to move the clusters little far so that I can see the edges (because now I can only see the whole grey color).

Comment: I would start by reducing the size of the vertices. Start with `vertex.size=4`  How  many vertices of each type do you have?

Comment: yes the image which I gave the link is `vertex.size=4`. typeA (930), typeB (110), typeC (3). Ofcourse typeC are very less but want them to bring on the top.

Comment: Any help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122201/how-to-rescale-the-plot-to-push-the-clusters-nodes-a-bit-further-apart-and-nam

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the code below works

```
plot(net,
     edge.width = E(net)$weight,
     vertex.color = factor(V(net)$name),
     mark.groups = split(V(net)$name,V(net)$Clusters))
```

which gives
[image]